# lxc list/lxc-fs --fancy empty after conjure-up openstack with novalxd install

Tags: openstack, conjure-up

I have tried to install openstack on a single machine to play around with it. I used conjure-up to do so and the install goes with no warnings nor errors.

I tried to install it both on Ubuntu 16.04 server and desktop, but post install I always end up with an empty list when I use "lxc list" or "lxc-fs" which is not expected and also prevents me to find out the ip of the instances I would like to ssh to.

The openstack install was performed from a clean install of Ubuntu in both case.
Has anybody faced this issue? Or can anyone get me on some path to figure out what's going on as I am out of ideas?

Answer (score 0):

We are fixing this issue this week, but for now you can reach your containers via `conjure-up.lxc`. Currently, we were bundling lxd in our snap but thats changing since lxd 2.17 will become feature parity with the debian packaged version.